# Bing Translate with POST

Tags: php, bing

I using Bing Translate with GET (curl) method and everything work fine.

But now i need using POST mothod, add new line:

```
$postData = array('text'=>'home', 'to'=>'it', 'from'=>'en');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
```

And now get error:

"Error Status Code: 'InternalServerError'

Details: The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the server logs for more details."
BING does not support POST?

Answer (score 1):

you can find the implementation at
http://code.google.com/p/micrsoft-translator-php-wrapper/
and you can see the demo also
http://renjith.co.in/translate/

Answer (score 0):

BING support POST: http://wangpidong.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-use-new-bing-translator-api-with.html

(see step 4)

Comment: He make POST action, but all data add into address (text=hello&from=en&to=zh-CHS'), so he actually use like GET method. I do not want to add in the address translation text.